# how to use subprocess.call

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm using `subprocess.call` on windows and in order to execute the following code I have to add the arg `shell=True` and can't use `shell=False`.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("F:\\A_1000_Times.mp4" , shell=True)
exit()
```

Whenever I use `shell=False` it returns:

> WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Could someone be able to tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Hi yousef, welcome to SO. There is a simple reason why you are not allowed to upload images as a new user: Don't include images of your code, instead paste it into your question and use the code formatting button to indent it automatically by four spaces

Comment: thanks for your comment but i don't understand  why not to paste a picture of my code it's much easier. for the second time thank you for your attention

Comment: It is much easier and convenient for you, but makes it much more complicated for someone to just take your code and run it on their computer. Read up on it [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is telling it all: `WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`. You are providing a `.mp4` file which is not an executable per se. What you are trying to do is start the default application associated with the extension `.mp4` in your os and have it play that file. For this the [os.startfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile) method exists:

```
os.startfile("F:\\A_1000_Times.mp4")
```

Comment: thank you very much. it worked perfectly. but can you tell me what `subprocess.call` do . i read about it but i didn't git it especially after what you said it made me confused.